# Dataset multiplication, multiplying the ratios of DT2 with totals of DT1, taking DT2 characteristics

Tags: r, data.table

I have two databases `DT1` and `DT2`:

```
library(data.table)
DT1 <- structure(list(State = structure(c(1L, 8L, 9L, 10L), .Label = c("Alabama", 
"Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas", "California", "Colorado", "Connecticut", 
"Delaware", "District Of Columbia", "Florida", "Georgia", "Hawaii", 
"Idaho", "Illinois", "Indiana", "Iowa", "Kansas", "Kentucky", 
"Louisiana", "Maine", "Maryland", "Massachusetts", "Michigan", 
"Minnesota", "Mississippi", "Missouri", "Montana", "Nebraska", 
"Nevada", "New Hampshire", "New Jersey", "New Mexico", "New York", 
"North Carolina", "North Dakota", "Ohio", "Oklahoma", "Oregon", 
"Pennsylvania", "Rhode Island", "South Carolina", "South Dakota", 
"Tennessee", "Texas", "Utah", "Vermont", "Virginia", "Washington", 
"West Virginia", "Wisconsin", "Wyoming", "United States", "Other Areas  14", 
"X Money Amounts Are In Thousands Of Dollars", "Other Areas  19"
), class = "factor"), year = c(1995, 1995, 1995, 1995), AGI = c(10, 
20, 30, 25), NoR = c(11, 22, 
20, 10)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))

DT1
                  State year AGI NoR
1:              Alabama 1995  10  11
2:             Delaware 1995  20  22
3: District Of Columbia 1995  30  20
4:              Florida 1995  25  10

DT2 <- structure(list(wvs_mar_stat = c(1, 1, 1), irs_age_cat = c("Under 26", 
"26 under 35", "35 under 45"), range = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L
), .Label = c("from_1_to_5000", "from_5000_to_10000", "from_10000_to_15000", 
"from_15000_to_20000", "from_20000_to_25000", "from_25000_to_30000", 
"from_30000_to_40000", "from_40000_to_50000", "from_50000_to_75000", 
"from_75000_to_100000", "from_100000_to_200000", "from_200000_to_500000", 
"from_500000_to_1000000", "from_1000000_to_1500000", "from_1500000_to_2000000", 
"from_2000000_to_5000000", "from_5000000_to_10000000", "No_Adjusted_Gross_Income"
), class = "factor"), rat_AGI = c(0.1, 0.2, 
0.2), rat_NoR = c(0.3, 0.2, 
0.1)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))

DT2
   wvs_mar_stat irs_age_cat          range rat_AGI rat_NoR
1:            1    Under 26 from_1_to_5000     0.1     0.3
2:            1 26 under 35 from_1_to_5000     0.2     0.2
3:            1 35 under 45 from_1_to_5000     0.2     0.1
```

I would like to multiply `rat_AGI` and `rat_NoR` of `DT2` with `AGI` and `NoR` from `DT1` respectively, adding the row characteristics of `DT2`.

Desired outcome:

```
DTout <- structure(list(State = structure(c(1L, 8L, 9L, 10L), .Label = c("Alabama", 
"Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas", "California", "Colorado", "Connecticut", 
"Delaware", "District Of Columbia", "Florida", "Georgia", "Hawaii", 
"Idaho", "Illinois", "Indiana", "Iowa", "Kansas", "Kentucky", 
"Louisiana", "Maine", "Maryland", "Massachusetts", "Michigan", 
"Minnesota", "Mississippi", "Missouri", "Montana", "Nebraska", 
"Nevada", "New Hampshire", "New Jersey", "New Mexico", "New York", 
"North Carolina", "North Dakota", "Ohio", "Oklahoma", "Oregon", 
"Pennsylvania", "Rhode Island", "South Carolina", "South Dakota", 
"Tennessee", "Texas", "Utah", "Vermont", "Virginia", "Washington", 
"West Virginia", "Wisconsin", "Wyoming", "United States", "Other Areas  14", 
"X Money Amounts Are In Thousands Of Dollars", "Other Areas  19"
), class = "factor"), year = c(1995, 1995, 1995, 1995), AGI = c(10, 
20, 30, 25), NoR = c(11, 22, 
20, 10)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))

DTout <- rbind(DTout, DTout, DTout)
DTout$State <- sort(DTout$State)
DTout <- cbind(DTout, DT2)
DTout <- setDT(DTout)[, AGI:= rat_AGI*AGI]
DTout <- setDT(DTout)[, NoR:= rat_NoR*NoR]

                   State year AGI NoR wvs_mar_stat irs_age_cat          range rat_AGI rat_NoR
 1:              Alabama 1995 1.0 3.3            1    Under 26 from_1_to_5000     0.1     0.3
 2:              Alabama 1995 4.0 4.4            1 26 under 35 from_1_to_5000     0.2     0.2
 3:              Alabama 1995 6.0 2.0            1 35 under 45 from_1_to_5000     0.2     0.1
 4:             Delaware 1995 2.5 3.0            1    Under 26 from_1_to_5000     0.1     0.3
 5:             Delaware 1995 2.0 2.2            1 26 under 35 from_1_to_5000     0.2     0.2
 6:             Delaware 1995 4.0 2.2            1 35 under 45 from_1_to_5000     0.2     0.1
 7: District Of Columbia 1995 3.0 6.0            1    Under 26 from_1_to_5000     0.1     0.3
 8: District Of Columbia 1995 5.0 2.0            1 26 under 35 from_1_to_5000     0.2     0.2
 9: District Of Columbia 1995 2.0 1.1            1 35 under 45 from_1_to_5000     0.2     0.1
10:              Florida 1995 2.0 6.6            1    Under 26 from_1_to_5000     0.1     0.3
11:              Florida 1995 6.0 4.0            1 26 under 35 from_1_to_5000     0.2     0.2
12:              Florida 1995 5.0 1.0            1 35 under 45 from_1_to_5000     0.2     0.1
```

Is there a less messy way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a convenience function such as `crossing` in data.table. The closest I could think of is `CJ` (e.g. `do.call(CJ, c(DT1[, .(State, year)],DT2[, .(wvs_mar_stat, irs_age_cat, range)], unique = TRUE))`), but it will leave all the non-join column out.

The hack I could think of, is to create ids in both data sets and join on them (if your data sets aren't unique, you can create ids using `rleid` or `.GRP`)

```
## Some meaningless id 
DT1[, id := 1] ; DT2[, id := 1]

## Join by the meaningless id
DTout <- 
  DT1[DT2, on = .(id), allow.cartesian = TRUE # in order to get a larger output than DT1 + DT2
      ][, `:=`(AGI = AGI * rat_AGI, NoR = NoR * rat_NoR)]
DTout
#                    State year AGI NoR id wvs_mar_stat irs_age_cat          range rat_AGI rat_NoR
#  1:              Alabama 1995 1.0 3.3  1            1    Under 26 from_1_to_5000     0.1     0.3
#  2:             Delaware 1995 2.0 6.6  1            1    Under 26 from_1_to_5000     0.1     0.3
#  3: District Of Columbia 1995 3.0 6.0  1            1    Under 26 from_1_to_5000     0.1     0.3
#  4:              Florida 1995 2.5 3.0  1            1    Under 26 from_1_to_5000     0.1     0.3
#  5:              Alabama 1995 2.0 2.2  1            1 26 under 35 from_1_to_5000     0.2     0.2
#  6:             Delaware 1995 4.0 4.4  1            1 26 under 35 from_1_to_5000     0.2     0.2
#  7: District Of Columbia 1995 6.0 4.0  1            1 26 under 35 from_1_to_5000     0.2     0.2
#  8:              Florida 1995 5.0 2.0  1            1 26 under 35 from_1_to_5000     0.2     0.2
#  9:              Alabama 1995 2.0 1.1  1            1 35 under 45 from_1_to_5000     0.2     0.1
# 10:             Delaware 1995 4.0 2.2  1            1 35 under 45 from_1_to_5000     0.2     0.1
# 11: District Of Columbia 1995 6.0 2.0  1            1 35 under 45 from_1_to_5000     0.2     0.1
# 12:              Florida 1995 5.0 1.0  1            1 35 under 45 from_1_to_5000     0.2     0.1
```

---

As a side note, data.table (similar to Pandas) has *update-in-place* functionality, hence please **don't do**

1. `DTout <- setDT(DTout)` rather just `setDT(DTout)`
2. `DTout <- setDT(DTout)[, AGI:= rat_AGI*AGI]` rathe just `DTout[, AGI:= rat_AGI*AGI]`

Comment: Thank you very much! Works very well. With respect to your side note, I know I shouldn't. I had some problems with the data set not updating in the past (most likely because I did not understand exactly what I was doing), because of which I just put it in everywhere to be sure. I will attempt to let this bad habit go ;)

Comment: Usually all the in-place functions begin with `set`, e.g. `setDT`, `setcolorder`, `setorder`, `set`, etc. Except that, only `:=` updates in place. All the rest of the functions won't update in-place IIRC. I agree that there is a lot of rules to remember in data.table. After using Pandas for a while, I feel like their idea having `inplace` argument in all the functions is a bit more intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a `data.table` method, but you could use `dplyr` and `tidyr`:

```r
DT1 %>%
  crossing(DT2) %>%
  mutate(AGI = AGI * rat_AGI,
         NoR = NoR * rat_NoR)
```

which returns

```r
# A tibble: 12 x 9
   State                 year   AGI   NoR wvs_mar_stat irs_age_cat range          rat_AGI rat_NoR
   <fct>                <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>        <dbl> <chr>       <fct>            <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 Alabama               1995   2     2.2            1 26 under 35 from_1_to_5000     0.2     0.2
 2 Alabama               1995   2     1.1            1 35 under 45 from_1_to_5000     0.2     0.1
 3 Alabama               1995   1     3.3            1 Under 26    from_1_to_5000     0.1     0.3
 4 Delaware              1995   4     4.4            1 26 under 35 from_1_to_5000     0.2     0.2
 5 Delaware              1995   4     2.2            1 35 under 45 from_1_to_5000     0.2     0.1
 6 Delaware              1995   2     6.6            1 Under 26    from_1_to_5000     0.1     0.3
 7 District Of Columbia  1995   6     4              1 26 under 35 from_1_to_5000     0.2     0.2
 8 District Of Columbia  1995   6     2              1 35 under 45 from_1_to_5000     0.2     0.1
 9 District Of Columbia  1995   3     6              1 Under 26    from_1_to_5000     0.1     0.3
10 Florida               1995   5     2              1 26 under 35 from_1_to_5000     0.2     0.2
11 Florida               1995   5     1              1 35 under 45 from_1_to_5000     0.2     0.1
12 Florida               1995   2.5   3              1 Under 26    from_1_to_5000     0.1     0.3
```